# Writing $\alpha||\mathbf{u}^\dagger(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v})||^2 + ||\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}||^2$ in a compact form.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have an expression
$$\alpha||\mathbf{u}^\dagger(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v})||^2 + ||\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}||^2$$
where $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are complex vectors in $\mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}$, and $\alpha$ is a scalar. Here $(.)^\dagger$ shows the conjugate transpose as well. If the dimension $N=1$ (where vectors are being scalar), we can simplify the expression as given below:

$$(\alpha |u|^2 +1)|u-v|^2$$
But I couldn't figure out if I am able to write (for vectorial case)
$$ (\alpha||\mathbf{u}||^2 + 1) ||\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}||^2 $$
which seems mathematically incorrect.

My goal is to simplify the first expression given above in a compact form having a multiplication term $||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2$$?

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: I'm not very clear what $||\mathbf{u}^\dagger(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v})||^2$ means, since $\mathbf{u}^\dagger\mathbf{u}$ appears to be a scalar, since it's a transpose of a row vector times a row vector, and yet that looks like the length squared of a vector.

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 2):

We could do
$$
  \alpha||\mathbf u^\dagger(\mathbf u - \mathbf v)||^2 
    + ||\mathbf u - \mathbf v||^2
  = \alpha[(\mathbf u - \mathbf v)^\dagger\mathbf u][\mathbf u^\dagger(\mathbf u - \mathbf v)]
    + (\mathbf u - \mathbf v)^\dagger(\mathbf u - \mathbf v)
  = (\mathbf u - \mathbf v)^\dagger[\alpha\mathbf u\mathbf u^\dagger + 1](\mathbf u - \mathbf v)
$$
since $||\mathbf x||^2 = \mathbf x^\dagger\mathbf x$ for vector $\mathbf x$ and $||x||^2 = x^*x$ for scalar $x$. The $1$ in the final expression is to be interpreted as an identity matrix. You can see how this is a generalization of the scalar expression you wanted to mimic.

This has a nice interpretation of $\alpha\mathbf u\mathbf u^\dagger + 1$ defining an inner product, and applying that inner product to find the (square of) the distance between $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$.

Comment: That is very something that I'm looking for! I hope I can go on with this. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer but I am just able to write it.
Here is my simplification, I hope that there is no typo.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    & ||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2 + \alpha||\mathbf{u}^\dagger ( \mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v})||^2 \\
    = & ||\mathbf{u}- \mathbf{v}||^2 + \alpha (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v})^\dagger \mathbf{u} \mathbf{u}^\dagger ( \mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}) \\
    = &||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2 + \alpha ( ||\mathbf{u}||^2 - \mathbf{v}^\dagger \mathbf{u})(||\mathbf{u}||^2 - \mathbf{u}^\dagger \mathbf{v}) \\
    = &||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2 + \alpha ( ||\mathbf{u}||^4 - ||\mathbf{u}||^2(\mathbf{u}^\dagger\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v}^\dagger \mathbf{u}) + ||\mathbf{u}||^2 ||\mathbf{v}||^2) \\
    = &||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2 + \alpha ||\mathbf{u}||^2 ( ||\mathbf{u}||^2 - (\mathbf{u}^\dagger\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v}^\dagger \mathbf{u}) + ||\mathbf{v}||^2) \\
    = &||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2 + \alpha ||\mathbf{u}||^2 ( ||\mathbf{u}||^2 - (\mathbf{u}^\dagger\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v}^\dagger \mathbf{u}) + ||\mathbf{v}||^2) \\
    = &||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2 + \alpha ||\mathbf{u}||^2 ||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2 \\
    = &||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2 \left( 1+ \alpha ||\mathbf{u}||^2 \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: In the third step you pose $^†^† = ‖‖^2‖‖^2$, but his is only true if $$ and $$ are parallel (Cauchy-Schwartz!).

Comment: Thnx for the reply. How I missed that! :)